# Prove that divergence and curl free vector field is a constant vector field

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields

I need to prove the fact that a vector field $\vec{B}$ that is divergence and curl free, is a constant vector field.

I have attempted to prove this by referring to the divergence, but realized that this will not work since the fields of the vector field not necessary must be all constants to obtain a divergence of 0. I believe that both properties (divergence free and curl free) should be used to prove it.

Comment: I think you need some condition on the domain and also boundedness to prove that its constant.

Comment: Try writing out the divergence and curl in component form. You should have 4 equations, one for each component of the curl, and one from the divergence. Substitute the equations into each other and maybe integrate once, and you should get the result in a straightforward manner.

Comment: rajb245, I attempted this earlier today with a matrix to solve the system. I am going to try it again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is not true. If you take any harmonic function $u \colon \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ and let $\vec{B} = \mathrm{grad}(u)$ then $\mathrm{curl}(\vec{B}) = \mathrm{curl}(\mathrm{grad}(u)) = 0$ and $\mathrm{div}(\vec{B}) = \mathrm{div}(\mathrm{grad}(u)) = \Delta u = 0$. For most harmonic functions, $\vec{B}$ won't be a constant vector field.

Comment: I cant question your answer, but I will list some more details of my exercise. In the exercise I am supposed to simplify a vector expression as far as possible. So the vector field B is an arbitrary vector field which has these two properties. My teacher has told me that I should prove that B is a constant field with only the help of these two properties, in order to proceed in the simplification of the expression

Comment: If that's what your teacher said, your teacher is wrong.  For a concrete example, $y {\bf i} + x {\bf j} = [y,x,0[$ is divergence free and curl free, but is not constant.

Answer (score 0):

By specifying the vector field's divergence and curl you still have ambiguity in its normal component at the boundary. If you require that the normal component at the boundary is a constant vector then the vector field throughout the volume is a constant one. Similarly if you require that the normal component to the boundary vanishes then the vector field is identically zero.